# Error al installar express con "npm install express"

Tags: express, npm

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: Socket connection timeout

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: carpeta...
```

Lo mismo me paso anteriormente con la direccion *https://registry.npmmirror.com/accepts* (que es la que usa npm por defecto para instalar).

Saben que pueda ser?

Comment: Estas detrás de un servidor proxy? pueden ser muchas cosas, como primer paso, verifica que tienes la ultima version de npm

Comment: Un problema temporal de red o un problema con la versión de `npm`, o incluso algo relacionado con el antivirus. Es muy difícil saberlo.

Comment: npm -v
9.6.6
node -v
v20.1.0

Saben decirme si esta bien o si deberia actualizar, o como podria hacer para intentar actualizar a la ultima version?